# Checking for a digit in a string - without loops and without libraries

Tags: python

I want to have a string, for example I want to type in 'I have 2 dogs' and I want the shell to return `True` (A function will do) if a number is shown in the string.
I found it so hard to code without using any loops and without any 're' or 'string' library.

Any help please?

Example:

```
input: "I own 23 dogs"
output: True

input: "I own one dog"
output: False
```

Comment: any reason for not using loop/string library?

Comment: In my learnings they didn't teach us this yet so I don't want to do anything too ahead

Comment: @hansolo that uses the 're' library

Comment: `return any(y.isdigit() for y in x)`

Comment: Folks, they haven't learnt about loops yet so why are you suggesting generators/list comphrensions? That said, the question is bad and likely a dupe

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = "I own 23 dogs"
>>> print(bool([i for i in a if i.isdigit()]))
True

>>> b = "I own some dogs"
>>> print(bool([i for i in b if i.isdigit()]))
False
```

However the better solution is to use `any` and use generators instead of lists for better performance (just like @Alderven solution):

```
>>> a = "I own 23 dogs"
>>> any(i.isdigit() for i in a)
True
```

Comment: this builds the whole list, not a good idea when you can short circuit with `any()`

Comment: @Chris_Rands you are right. I update my answer

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension helps you:

```
def is_digit(string):
    return any(c.isdigit() for c in string)

print(is_digit("I own 23 dogs"))
print(is_digit("I own one dog"))
```

Output:

```
True
False
```